# iOS App IPA file upload failed

Tags: ios, ios7, application-loader

I want upload iOS application to iTunesConnect from ApplicationLoader.

But the upload failed. Error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I created icons, And putted image to resources folder.

- icon.png (57x57)
- icon@2x.png (114x114)
- icon-72.png (72x72)
- icon-72@2x.png (144x144)
- icon-76.png (76x76)
- icon-76@2x.png
  (152x152)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Read the message. Take special note of the dimensions of the missing image. Go through your list and check if that image is there.

Answer (score 2):

After the update to iOS 7, you are required to use different icon sizes. See the [iOS Guidelines for more detail](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

Basically, you need a 120x120 icon, among other sizes.

Comment: thanks comment. I tried change icons.
icon.png (57x57)  -> icon.png (60x60) 
icon@2x.png (114x114) -> icon@2x.png (120x120)
But upload failed.

Comment: Make sure everything is correct in your `info.plist` file, your first 57x57 icon needs to be 60x60 as well. Asset Catalog can help you with all of this as well.

Answer (score 1):

The size requirements have changed for iOS 7.0.

It's worth switching to an asset catalog to store them in if you're using XCode 5, as it gives you a visible representation of what you have and what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you are already added icon images for all required sizes
you can generate icons for all required sizes simply from the following site

```
https://makeappicon.com/
```